# Why does my desktop lock up when I copy lots of files to a USB drive?

Tags: linux, kde, btrfs

My desktop is usually very responsive, even under heavy load. But when I copy files to a USB drive, it always locks up after some time. By "lock up", I mean:

- Moving focus from one window to another can take 10-20s
- Switching desktops can take 10-20s
- Videos don't update anymore (in YouTube, the audio continues to play, only the video freezes)

The system load isn't exceptionally high when this happens. Sometimes, I see a lot of white on xosview indicating that the kernel is busy somewhere.

At first glance, it looks as if copying files to the USB drive would interfere somehow with compiz but I can't imagine what the connection could be.

Here is the output of `htop`:

[image: Output of htop shortly after the hang]

Here is the output of `iostat -c -z -t -x -d 1` during a 2 minute hang:

```
19.07.2012 20:38:22
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1,27    0,00    0,38   37,52    0,00   60,84

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sdg               0,00     2,00    0,00  216,00     0,00 109248,00  1011,56   247,75  677,69    0,00  677,69   4,63 100,00
```

As you can see, only the external harddisk is active. Here is the complete log: http://pastebin.com/YNWTAkh4

The hang started at 20:38:01 and ended at 20:40:19.

Software information:

- openSUSE 12.1
- KDE 4.7.x
- Filesystems: reiserfs and btrfs on my internal harddisk, btrfs on the USB drive

Comment: Have you tried mounting the USB drive `sync` to see what effect (if any) this has?

Comment: A disadvantage of USB is the fact that it heavily relies on the CPU for IO. What sort of CPU do does your system have? Append the output of `grep name /proc/cpuinfo` to your question please.

Comment: Do you drag and drop the files using dolphin? If so, try `cp` from the command line to exclude possible dolphin bugs.

Comment: @JariLaamanen: I'm using `rsync` from the command line.

Comment: @jippie: I have an i7-3770 and 16GB RAM. CPU power shouldn't be a problem. The system doesn't swap when it happend. I can see about 10GB cached data in memory in `xosview`

Comment: Can you add the output of `top` to your question? Make sure it shows the separate cores (strike `1`) and the State column 'S' is shown.

Comment: @jippie: Not really because the UI locks up when it happens, so I can't make a screenshot. I'll try to create a log with `iostat -c -z -d 1`

Comment: I had the same problem with `cp` instead of `rsync`. Using `nice` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first guess was `btrfs` since the I/O processes of this file system sometimes take over. But it wouldn't explain why X locks up.

Looking at the interrupts, I see this:

```
# cat /proc/interrupts 
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7       
  0:        179          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:          6          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  8:          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:         10          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      i8042
 16:    3306384          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1, nvidia, mei, eth1
```

Well, duh. The USB driver uses the same IRQ as the graphics card and it is first in the chain. If it locks up (because the file system does something expensive), the graphics card starves (and the network, too).

Answer (score 2):

I had seen similar problems with [openSUSE](http://www.opensuse.org/) 12.1's linux-3.1 kernel and found that disabling transparent huge pages helped:

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

The underlying problem is that if an application allocates 4MB or more, the kernel will try to give it a huge page, for which it needs a whole contiguous 4MB RAM. Now, if there are many dirty pages around, that still need to be written to a slow USB device, it waits for that IO to finish before continuing with the memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, this probably has to do with the kernel hugepages setup.
I know several people with this problem. You can find several documentation about it in the web, e.g.

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=112846&p=1
- http://lwn.net/Articles/467328/
- http://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=2062.0
- [Slow performance when copying files to and from USB devices](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23003/slow-performance-when-copying-files-to-and-from-usb-devices)

I have completely fixed the problem on my setup by doing the following. Notice YMMV, not all the fixes below may be necessary, and maybe they'll not be sufficient.
I may have forgotten something to be honest. Anyhow that's my setup and it works.

- Use linux-ck kernel
- `echo madvise > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled`
- `echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag`

Answer (score -2):

Change the cable. Remove oxid from usb port/cables.

Comment: It needs to be a little more elaborate.  Please see the [FAQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq)