# Why is ping so slow?

Tags: networking, performance

My setup:

Server in the cellar + GBit switch. Long cable to the roof. GBit switch. I have three computers in the roof. One has only 100MBit ethernet, one laptop with GBit and a new computer.

Ping times from the old 100MBit computer: 0.5ms on average
Ping times from laptop: 0.4ms on average
Ping times from my new computer: 5ms or 30ms or 200ms on average but I often see ping times up to 980ms. In general, the throughput is very unstable.

I replaced the switch in the roof. No change.
I replace the cable which connects the new computer to the roof switch. No change.
I installed a PCI network card with an Intel GBit chip (82541PI) and used that instead of the built in Realtek RTL8111/8168B. No change. Yes, I'm sure that I plugged the cable into the correct port because I now get a different IP address from my DHCP server.

The very same network card worked perfectly find on my old computer using the same operating system (openSUSE 12.1).

`ifconfig` says:

```
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:15679 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:13077 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
```

`ethtool` says:

```
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
```

What could be causing this behavior?

**[EDIT]** I found something interesting:

```
# cat /proc/interrupts 
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7       
  0:        178          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:          6          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  8:          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:         10          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      i8042
 16:    3302428          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1, nvidia, mei, eth1
 17:        184          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   snd_hda_intel
 23:      16721          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2
```

As you can see, interrupt 16 serves one USB port, the graphics card, "mei" (?) and `eth1`.

I guess that would explain why it's slow. How do I assign interrupts in 2012?

Comment: When you run `ping` do all pings come back?  That is, does your setupu loose pings or packets?

Comment: I have 0% packet loss. It's just slow. Maybe a bad IRQ was assigned to the network card?

Comment: when you are getting high ping times, have you monitored CPU utilization on both sides to validate that you are not somehow very busy and getting scheduler delays?

Comment: You could try to move the computers next to one another, and connect them using a short crossover cable. That should rule out effects due to bad switches, long cables, electric interference along the way, and so on. Yes I know, the other computer works fine over that distance, but that might be a case of it being more tolerant to noisy signals or similar.

Comment: In my case it was a faulty router, you can figure it out like in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548426/why-is-ping-slow-on-domain-solving/548553#548553).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My mainboard is an ASUS P8Z77-M. The BIOS version was 0802. This bios has a bug: It assigns the same IRQ (16) to all high-throughput devices which can cause all kinds of problems (like [freezing the desktop when you copy files to an USB device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42824/why-does-my-desktop-lock-up-when-i-copy-lots-of-files-to-a-usb-drive)).

Upgrading to version 1206 improved the situation. The network card now gets its own IRQ and the ping times are now where they should be:

```
64 bytes from ds.digulla (192.168.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.197 ms
64 bytes from ds.digulla (192.168.0.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.252 ms
64 bytes from ds.digulla (192.168.0.3): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.200 ms
64 bytes from ds.digulla (192.168.0.3): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.239 ms
64 bytes from ds.digulla (192.168.0.3): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.215 ms
64 bytes from ds.digulla (192.168.0.3): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.204 ms
64 bytes from ds.digulla (192.168.0.3): icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.244 ms
64 bytes from ds.digulla (192.168.0.3): icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.190 ms
^C
--- ds.digulla ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.190/0.217/0.252/0.027 ms
```