# Why is ping slow on domain solving?

Tags: bash, networking, ping

Why this big difference in times if the domain name is resolved by **ping** itself, versus **getent** externally?

---

```
$ time ping -c1 "google.com""
0% packet loss
0m5,064s
```

---

```
$ time (ip=$(getent ahostsv4 "google.es" | awk '{ print $1 }' |
head -n1); ping -c1 "${ip}")
0% packet loss
0m0,042s
```

Comment: `time` will tell how much time took the command to run, not how much time the *ping* took. If you `ping <bogus ip>`, `time` will tell you i.e. 10s, when there was never a real ping involved.

Comment: That's what I meant, that time isn't the actual ping but the tool trying to solve the name. The difference in times doing that same thing is big.

Comment: Try to run the commands several times in a row and you see that there's not a clear pattern... as far as I've tried.

Comment: First case always takes more than 5s, second case always less than 100ms.

Answer (score 3):

A **work-around** that succeeded was, on /etc/resolv.conf, adding:

```
options single-request-reopen
```

Suggesting the **root issue**:

> Sets RES_SNGLKUPREOP in _res.options. The resolver uses the same
>   socket for the A and AAAA requests. Some **hardware** mistakenly sends
>   back only one reply. When that happens the client system will sit and
>   wait for the second reply. Turning this option on changes this
>   behavior so that if two requests from the same port are not handled
>   correctly it will close the socket and open a new one before sending
>   the second request.

So disabling **IPv6** on my Google Wifi **router** fixed the problem.