# Why does mouse and cursor movement become erratic when I copy an entire memory stick to another stick?

Tags: linux, cache, slowdown

I copied a 16 GB USB memory stick to another 16 GB stick (cloned it), by using the
following command:

```
cp /dev/sdb /dev/sdd
```

It took about 27 minutes, and the cloning works. But during the entire copy process,
the mouse and cursor movement become erratic, and lag terribly. This makes using
the laptop during the copy almost impossible.

This happened to me on a previous occasion, so the effect is reproduci ble.

What causes this effect?
How do I stop the erratic behaviour?
Are you able to replicate the behaviour on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

> What causes this effect?

Probably SWAP use and dirty buffers coupled with most likely slow storage (i.e. HDD). More on it here: https://lwn.net/Articles/572911/

> How do I stop the erratic behaviour

Disable swap altogether + `cat /etc/sysctl.d/vm.conf` + use a newer kernel. If you're running something like Debian 9 or CentOS 7, your kernel could have this issue.

```
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 33554432
vm.dirty_bytes = 134217728
```

> Are you able to replicate the behaviour on your computer?

No, I have this workaround, SSD, SWAP is disabled and 64GB of RAM.

Also check this topic:

- [Why does my desktop lock up when I copy lots of files to a USB drive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42824/why-does-my-desktop-lock-up-when-i-copy-lots-of-files-to-a-usb-drive)